# Pickle custom classes and unpickle without access to these classes

Tags: python, pickle

Is it possible to include the object's class definitions into the pickled file, so that objects can be unpickled without providing the source code to these classes? Or perhaps there's another serialisation method/standard that can be used instead...

Pickling:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def __init__(self, foo):
...     self.foo = foo
...
>>>
>>> a = A('abc')
>>> a
<__main__.A object at 0x7f78ce7f3550>
>>> a.foo
'abc'
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('test.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
...     pickle.dump(a, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
...
>>>
```

Unpickle without access to class A:

```
>>> import pickle
>>>
>>>
>>> with open('test.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
...     b = pickle.load(handle)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'A' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I'm trying to create test data for some test cases and am wondering whether those test cases can be executed separate to the code that produced this data.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1: using `pickle`

This method only work when unpickle have access to class A.
In case of without access to class A, use Method 2.

```
import pickle

# Define the class:
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

# Create an object:
a = A('abc')

# Serialize the object to a byte string:
serialized = pickle.dumps(a, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# Write the byte string to a file:
with open('test.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    handle.write(serialized)

# Read the byte string from the file and deserialize it:
with open('test.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    serialized = handle.read()

b = pickle.loads(serialized)
print(b.foo)
```

Output: abc

### Method 2: using `dill`

```
import dill

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

# Create an object
a = A('abc')

# Serialize the object to a byte string
serialized = dill.dumps(a)

# Write the byte string to a file
with open('test.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    handle.write(serialized)
```

Put the following code to another file (i.e., file2.py), and run `python file2.py`, it works.

```
# Read the byte string from the file and deserialize it
with open('test.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    serialized = handle.read()

b = dill.loads(serialized)
print(b.foo)
```

Output: abc

Comment: That's assuming that class `A` is known to the read and write namespace. Try to put those parts (read with the class definition) into 2 separate files and try to run them. That should show the problem.

Comment: @orange put the code after "Read the byte string from the file and deserialize it:" to a separate file, the method 1 using `pickle` does not work, method 2 using `dill` work well.

Answer (score 0):

Using [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) instead of pickle seems to do the trick.

```
import dill as pickle
```